# Why does that border not covering up its contents

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-float, border

Here I am sharing a pen [here](https://codepen.io/durgeshpushpakar/pen/QWyywoG)
I have inserted 6 div.squares inside of div.container
I have set .squares css property float:left
**My doubt is-**
**When I gave a red border to the div.container, that border doesn't cover the 6 divs(instead the border shows up only on the top of the squares)as seen in the pen**
According to me, that border should cover up all the squares

[Click on this link to see the pen](https://codepen.io/durgeshpushpakar/pen/QWyywoG)

```css
 .square{
      padding-bottom:30%;
      width:30%;
      margin:10px; 
      background-color:brown;
      float:left;
    }
    .container{
      height:100%;
      max-width:600px;
      margin:20px auto;
      border:2px solid red;
      height:auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of the float: left

Check out how I did it.

```css
.square{
      padding-bottom:30%;
      width:30%;
      margin:10px; 
      background-color:brown;
    }
    .container{
      height:100%;
      max-width:600px;
      margin:20px auto;
      border:2px solid red;

    }
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
   
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works Thanks for the answer......dou you know how to do it if all the div.square are in div.container

Comment: Yes, just remove the div.row and whatever is in the .row style, just put it in the .container style. haha

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of `height: auto`. calling height twice could be causing the issue.